# How to identify all events affecting an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

I have an input field

```
<input id='target' type='text'>
```

and I would like to modify its value with javascript.  Normally, this would be as easy as doing

```
document.getElementById('target').value = 'new value';
```

However, this input field is embedded into a page that loads other scripts that could potentially interact with this field and make changes as well.

How can I find out all the scripts that change the value of this input without spelunking through all the code.  Is there some way to set a listener on the input field that logs all attempts to modify it?

Comment: Not really.  The answers to that question only pertain to elements that are bound by jQuery.  In my case, there could be vanilla javascript code responsible for the changes

Comment: There are answers to that question that do not rely on jQuery.  For example, see the second answer in the link I referred to above.